# I am writing an application to extract different parts of a C# script

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

I am using the [CSharpSyntaxTree](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Syntax-Analysis) and I have been able to extract the using statements, method and class definitions.The structure of my script is:

```
<using statements>
<executable code statements (may or may not be in a try-catch block)>
<method definitions>
<class definitions>
```

But now I am having an issue extracting all independent executable statements.
The line `var statementSyntaxes = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<StatementSyntax>().ToList();` gives me all statements in the script but I am not interested in statements in the methods and class definitions. Please, how do I filter them out and retrieve only the statements that stand alone?

Here is my code:

```
var sourceCode = source.ToString();
SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(sourceCode);
var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();
var members = root.Members;

// get all using statements
var usingCollector = new UsingCollector();
usingCollector.Visit(root);
var usingNames = String.Join("\n", usingCollector.Usings.Select(u => u.ToString()));                       

// get all methods
var methodDeclarationSyntaxes = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();
var usefulMethods = methodDeclarationSyntaxes.Where(m => m.Body != null);
var methodsScript = String.Join("\n", usefulMethods.Select(m => m.ToString()));

// get all classes
var classDeclarations = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().Select(c => c).ToList();                        
var classesScript = String.Join("\n", classDeclarations.Select(cc => cc.ToString()));

string customScript = $"{usingNames} \n{methodsScript} \n{classesScript}";

// get all executable statements
var statementSyntaxes = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<StatementSyntax>().ToList();
```

I am making an edit to the post:
So let's say I have a class with one method in it and I want to traverse through each of the executable statements in the method keeping in mind that some or all of these statements might be wrapped in a try-catch block. How do I achieve this, please?

Comment: The code-structure you describe isn't valid C#. You can't have executable code (methods or otherwise) outside of a `class`, only declarations (`using`, `namespace`, `interface`, etc.)

Comment: I understand your point as regards the code structure but this structure represents a Roslyn C# script and it always compiles and runs well. So it is valid in this context.

Comment: I suspect you don't want to look at *descendant* nodes, but *direct child nodes*.

Comment: Yes, direct child nodes

Comment: Interesting, I'd forgotten all about the [scripting API](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples) (they killed it off around late 2014 but apparently brought it back the following year). There is a little-used `c#-scripting-api` tag for questions, by the way. It needs a description but I lack the points to add one.